# django running pandas.read_sql on test database during the test returns empty DataFrame

Tags: django, pandas, testing, django-testing

I have functions that create some pandas dataframes from database I want to test the data in these dataframe but when I try to read raw sql from test database using `pandas.read_sql()` or mysql cursor excute it always returns empty DataFrame

```
class PlacementTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        p = Placement.objects.create(name='placement_test')

    def PlacementTestCase(self):
        db = sql.connect(
            host=settings.DATABASES["test_db"]["HOST"],
            database=settings.DATABASES["test_db"]["NAME"],
            user=settings.DATABASES["test_db"]["USER"],
            password=settings.DATABASES["test_db"]["PASSWORD"]
        )
        df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM myapp_placement", con=db)
        # I want to run tests on df but it returns Empty DataFrame...
```